# Login into dropbox using ftplib Python

Tags: python, networking, ftp, network-programming, ftp-client

I want to login into my dropbox account and upload/download files from it using python ftplib. Is this possible?

I tried doing

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP("dropbox.com", "myUserName","Password")
```

But this did not work.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox doesn't have a ftp service. You can read this article: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python

Comment: do you know any other website which does have an ftp service?

Comment: @Denzil There are lots of options for ftp. The real question is what you're actually trying to do where you need such a service programmatically.